# pcl surface reconstruction poisson

Tags: pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I was looking in pcl for surface reconstruction methods.

I found the poisson surface reconstruction which I would like to use.

However, I cannot find the include file #include <pcl/surface/poisson.h>

which is indicated [here](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/classpcl_1_1surface_1_1_poisson.html)

Since I have pcl installed with ROS, not the standalone version,

I searched for it in ros packages pcl, pcl_ros, perception_pcl, perception_pcl_addons ...

Do you know where I can find this header? Are there any pcl functionalities not included in ros?

Thanks

Miguel

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11439/pcl-surface-reconstruction-poisson/) by [Miguel Riem de Oliveira](https://answers.ros.org/users/1178/miguel-riem-de-oliveira/) on ROS Answers with karma: 254 on 2011-10-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not quite sure, but the programmer of the Poisson Surface reconstruction mailed me there were some problems with his code. For that reason it's not available in the trunk of pcl-1.2. I also tried to get it running correct, but it seems it's not working fully.
Ok, I'm not using ROS, so maybe it's changed and now available. But I don't think so.

---

Originally posted by [FrankJeroen](https://answers.ros.org/users/1200/frankjeroen/) with karma: 36 on 2011-10-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2